# SetDeviceGammaRamp api usage in universal windows app

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I used SetDeviceGammaRamp api in a console c# application and it worked well. But when the same is used in a universal windows app Error    "CS1620 Argument 2 must be passed with the 'ref' keyword" is appeared.

My requirement is to change Gamma value using a slider control.

Code area:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace Brightness
{
       /// <summary>
       /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a    Frame.
       /// </summary>
       public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
       {
           [DllImport("user32.dll")]
           public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

           [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
           public static extern bool SetDeviceGammaRamp(IntPtr hDC, ref RAMP lpRamp);

           [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
           public struct RAMP
           {
               [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
               public UInt16[] Red;
               [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
               public UInt16[] Green;
               [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
               public UInt16[] Blue;
           }

           public MainPage()
           {
                this.InitializeComponent();
           }

            public static void SetGamma(int gamma)
            {
                if (gamma <= 256 && gamma >= 1)
                {
                    RAMP ramp = new RAMP();
                    ramp.Red = new ushort[256];
                    ramp.Green = new ushort[256];
                    ramp.Blue = new ushort[256];
                    for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++)
                    {
                          int iArrayValue = i * (gamma + 128);

                          if (iArrayValue > 65535)
                          {
                               iArrayValue = 65535;
                          }
                          ramp.Red[i] = ramp.Blue[i] = ramp.Green[i] =  (ushort)iArrayValue;
                     }
                     SetDeviceGammaRamp(GetDC(IntPtr.Zero), ref ramp);
                 }
            }


             private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender,                                                                 RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
             {
                  Slider slider = sender as Slider;
                  if (slider != null)
                  {
                      int p = (int)slider.Value;
                      SetGamma(p);
                  }
              }
         }
    }

enter code here
```

Error: CS1620: Argument 2 must be passed with the 'ref' keyword

I am new to C# and Universal Windows App.
Please help.

Comment: There are a large number of legacy winapi functions that you cannot use in a UWP app.  Anything from user32.dll and gdi32.dll is off limits.  There is no alternative for SetDeviceGammaRamp().

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the gamma value using slider since it will slide down automatically when you try to change it. The application can't refer the value on sliding condition. Try to fix the sliding issue first. Then you can change the Gamma value using injection method.

Comment: What is injection method to change Gamma Value? Any references? Is it possible in Universal Windows App?